# Gravity Forms attach cart item attributes programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

It's quite the complicated issue, so let me dissect it into steps:

1) We're sending cart data (including Gravity Form attributes) from WEBSITE_A (source) to WEBSITE_B (target) using the WP REST API.

2) Cart data is sent from WEBSITE_A and received on WEBSITE_B successfully. The data is received on WEBSITE_B as a JSON object: https://jsonblob.com/83fac8e3-48c1-11ea-b41a-4f98a26d7b37

3) Products on both WEBSITE_A and WEBSITE_B are identical but, obviously, each product's ID is different. Therefore, we add products to the user's cart by matching on sku, the sku can be found in the above JSON Blob link.

4) However, something similar needs to be done to attach the "gravity_form_attributes" (in the JSON object) to the Gravity Form forms of the corresponding products. The product forms on WEBSITE_A and WEBSITE_B are NOT identical, so we'll need to find a way to populate a product's form attributes with data from above JSON object.

Is there any way to achieve this? The Gravity Forms documentation doesn't help either and their support told me to hire an external developer.

Comment: _“Does that make sense?”_ - as the very _beginning_ of a problem description, perhaps … But it totally lacks detail, that would make this answerable in any way, IMHO. You have given us no clue whatsoever, based on _what_ you intend to identify “corresponding” form fields here, for starters.

Comment: @04FS You're absolutely right, our apologies. We've now updated the question with data and extra details, hope this makes it possible for you to provide help.

Comment: Still unclear based on _what_ you want to populate the GF form attributes on B with that data from A then. If these attributes have different names, then you need to define somewhere, somehow, which field you want to map to what? The GF API has methods like `update_form` and `update_form_property`, so you probably want to use one of those.

Comment: Right, I want to populate form attributes on B with form attributes from A. So, somehow, I need to know how to map them. But I think you just mentioned what I was looking for: https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#update-form and https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#update-form-property. Will give it a try, thanks.